# Вывести похожие строки, если в них есть одинаковые значения в цикле?

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, строки, foreach

Имеется файл **MyLinks.txt** содержащий **url** адреса вида:

```
http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba-win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/361.40/361.40-dba-win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/230.33/230.33-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
.....................................................................
http://MyServer.tp/Program/399.07/399.07-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/353.30/353.30-dba-win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/355.60/355.60-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/340.40/340.40-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
.....................................................................
```

Далее я хочу показать только те адреса, которые содержат между собой **100%** совпадение только в части пути значения версии (**то есть тут: 353.62/353.62**). Далее я делаю так:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"MyLinks.txt"))
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\d{3}\.\d{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```

Вроде бы все работает, и действительно отображаются строки как нужно, **НО**, вместе с этим показываются и куча таких к примеру строк:

```
http://MyServer.tp/Program/353.30/353.30-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/355.60/355.60-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/361.40/361.40-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/311.63/311.63-dba-win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/399.07/399.07-dba-win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
```

А мне нужно всего навсего показывать строки у которых в пути одинаковые значения версии, и имеется на конце либо ...**-demo-expired**, либо ...**-original**, но я считаю, если будут одинаковые значения у строк, то и не нужно еще искать и по окончанию, я думаю это лишнее. **А выводится должно вот так:**

```
http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba--win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba--win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/320.20/320.20-dba--win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/320.20/320.20-dba--win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/280.80/280.80-dba--win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/280.80/280.80-dba--win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/160.60/160.60-dba--win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/160.60/160.60-dba--win10-64bit-original.zip
...................................................................
```

Я уже всю голову себе сломал, как это сделать и так пробовал:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"([0-9]{3})+\./([0-9]{2})+"*, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
     }
```

И вот так:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"([0-9]{3})+\./([0-9]{2})+"*, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"demo-expired.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) || (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"original.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))))
         {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
         }
```

Но он все равно показывает лишние похожие только по паттерну строки, как правильно в таком случае должно выглядеть условие?

Comment: `(\d{3}\.\d{2}\/?){2}`

Comment: К сожалению, не работает, все равно выводятся не только дубликаты строк, но и просто одиночные похожие по паттерну.

Comment: тогда непонятно, что вам нужно.

Comment: Чтобы выводились только строки в которых есть дубли:
`http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba--win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba--win10-64bit-original.zip
...`
А сейчас выводится так:
`http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba--win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/323.23/323.23-dba--win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/353.30/353.30-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip
http://MyServer.tp/Program/311.63/311.63-dba-win10-64bit-demo-expired.zip`

Comment: \d{3}\.\d{2}\.*-dba-win10-64bit-(demo-expired|original).zip

Comment: Что такое дубли? Повторение 323.23/323.23 в строке? так оно во всех строках повторяется

Comment: Я кажется включил телепата и гадалку и до меня дошло, что нужна группировка по версии XXX.XX, где у каждой такой группы будут 2 элемента (demo-expired и original), и если элемента не 2, - то отбросить эту группу, если же 2 - выводить группу.

Comment: @Blackmeser ну да! я же вроде все объяснил выше. Но да, строки может быть 2 повторяющиеся с demo-expired и original, а может и вовсе не быть, и да если нет таких отбросить, а есть выводим!

Comment: @aepot Вы в правильном русле мыслили, но я же все расписал в самом начале и с примерами, там нет ВСЕХ одинаковых строк, я для примера и разделителя специально использовал многоточие, думал поймете. Я же не буду файл сюда кидать со 100+ строками ))

Comment: Вот и сидел и думал, как это многоточие регуляркой отфильтровать, а его оказывается там нет!

Comment: @aeport -с количеством точек, эт да, я перегнул - каюсь.

Comment: Вопрос все-равно остается открытым, а вот [файл](https://dropmefiles.com/M0qem)

Comment: @Malcolm вы очень плохо расписали с точки зрения того, что именно вам нужно, и примеры не понятные. И одними только регулярными выражениями тут кажется не обойтись, т.к. вы используете регулярные выражения, которые работают в рамках ОДНОЙ строки. На основе вашего Regex.IsMatch вам нужно группировать данные, добавляйте в Dictionary<(int major, int minor),(string demo_expired, string original)>, сначала наполняйте Dictionary, записывая в demo_expired и в original пути, а потом смотрите по каждому ключу, что demo_expired и original не пустые, и если всё ок - выводите их.

Comment: Вот вам простой пример добавления записи с demo_expired: if (dic.ContainsKey((353, 30)))
{
    var val = dic[(353, 30)];
    val.demo_expired = "http://MyServer.tp/Program/353.30/353.30-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip";
    dic[(353, 30)] = val;
}
else
{
    dic.Add((353, 30), ("http://MyServer.tp/Program/353.30/353.30-dba-win10-64bit-original.zip", ""));
}